# Infinite scrolling repeats... I have no idea why

Tags: php, wordpress, infinite-scroll, pinterest

I'm modifying a wordpress site that's got the iPin theme (pinterest-style infinite scrolling theme) installed.

I want the first four "pins" to show specific links, and then after that for all the "pins" to be the natural flow of blog posts.

Instead, the first four are successfully displaying how I want, but then when you scroll down and the site load more pins, those same 'specific link' pins come up again, and then again when you scroll down again.

[This is the page I'm working with](http://www.anticipods.org) (please excuse the messiness - early stages of construction)

I tried making a string that changes once the four links are displayed and basically says "if it has changed don't show the links" but that didn't work at all.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance - here's the total code from my index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="container-fluid" style="width: 1100px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <div id="ajax-loader-masonry" class="ajax-loader"></div>
    <div id="masonry">


<?php //"create a pod about yourself" link <=====this is the first 'specific link' pin
?>

<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 220px; height:100px; padding:0px;background-color:#DDD;" <?php post_class('thumb');?> >
            <div class="thumb-holder">

<a href="create-a-pod-about-yourself" class="create-a-pod-about-yourself-link-pod" style="padding:7px;">
<p class="create-a-pod-about-yourself-link-pod">Add pod:<br/>Introduce yourself<br/><br/></p></a>
            </div>
</div>      

<?php //"create a project pod" link <=====this is the second 'specific link' pin
?>

<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 220px; height:100px; padding:0px;background-color:#DDD;" <?php post_class('thumb');?> >
            <div class="thumb-holder">

<a href="create-a-project-pod" class="create-a-project-pod-link-pod" style="padding:7px;">
<p class="create-a-project-pod-link-pod">Add pod:<br/>Promote a project<br/><br/></p></a>
            </div>
</div>      

<?php //"create an idea pod" link <=====this is the third 'specific link' pin
?>

<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 220px; height:100px; padding:0px;background-color:#DDD;" <?php post_class('thumb');?> >
            <div class="thumb-holder">

<a href="create-an-idea-pod" class="create-an-idea-pod-link-pod" style="padding:7px;">
<p class="create-an-idea-pod-link-pod">Add pod:<br/>Share an idea<br/><br/></p></a>
            </div>
</div>  

<?php //"create a question pod" link  <=====this is the fourth 'specific link' pin
?>

<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 220px; height:100px; padding:0px;background-color:#DDD;" <?php post_class('thumb');?> >
            <div class="thumb-holder">

<a href="create-a-question-pod" class="create-a-question-pod-link-pod" style="padding:7px;">
<p class="create-a-question-pod-link-pod">Add pod:<br/>Ask a question<br/><br/></p></a>
            </div>
</div>  

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>




<?php //====now begins the infinitely scrolling list of normal blog posts
?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php post_class('thumb');?> style="padding:0px; background-color:
<?php $category = get_the_category($postID);
foreach (get_the_category() as $category) {
    if($category->name=='People'){
    echo '#FCC';
    }
else if($category->name=='Projects'){
    echo '#CCF';
}
else if($category->name=='Ideas'){
    echo '#CFC';
}
}
?>
;">
            <div class="thumb-holder">

<?php// if($category->name=='People'){
?>

                <div class="masonry-actionbar">
                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#respond"><i class="icon-comment"></i> <?php _e('Comment', 'ipin'); ?></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('View', 'ipin'); ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'medium');
                        $imgwidth = $imgsrc[1];
                        $imgheight = $imgsrc[2];
                        $imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
                    } elseif ($postimages = get_children("post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=0")) {
                        foreach($postimages as $postimage) {
                            $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($postimage->ID, 'medium');
                            $imgwidth = $imgsrc[1];
                            $imgheight = $imgsrc[2];
                            $imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
                        }
                    } elseif (preg_match('/<img [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', get_the_content(), $match) != FALSE) {
                        $imgsrc = $match[1];
                    } else {
                        $imgsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/blank.gif';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $imgsrc; $imgsrc = ''; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"  style="<?php if ($imgwidth != '') { ?>width:220px;height:<?php echo round(220/$imgwidth*$imgheight); ?>px;<?php } else { ?>width:220px;height:220px;<?php } ?>" />


                </a>
            </div>

<div class="thumbtitle" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; COLOR:#ee4949;"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="thumbtitle"><?php the_content(); ?></div>           

            <div class="masonry-meta<?php $show_avatars = get_option('show_avatars'); $comments_number = get_comments_number(); if ($comments_number == 0 && $show_avatars == '0') { echo ' text-align-center'; } ?>">
                <?php if ($show_avatars == '1') { ?>

                <div class="masonry-meta-comment">
                <?php } ?>
                    <span class="masonry-meta-content" style="font-size:15px;"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
                <?php if ($show_avatars == '1') { ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <?php
            if ('0' != $frontpage_comments_number = of_get_option('frontpage_comments_number')) {
                $args = array(
                    'number' => $frontpage_comments_number,
                    'post_id' => $post->ID,
                    'status' => 'approve'
                );
                $comments = get_comments($args);
                foreach($comments as $comment) {
                ?>
                <div class="masonry-meta">
                    <?php if ($show_avatars == '1') { ?>
                    <div class="masonry-meta-avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email , '30'); ?></div>
                    <div class="masonry-meta-comment">
                    <?php } ?>
                        <span class="masonry-meta-author"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></span> 
                        <?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_avatars == '1') { ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                }
                if ($comments_number > $frontpage_comments_number) {
                ?>
                <div class="masonry-meta text-align-center">
                    <span class="masonry-meta-author">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>/#navigation" title="<?php _e('View all', 'ipin'); ?> <?php echo $comments_number; ?> <?php _e('comments', 'ipin') ?>"><?php _e('View all', 'ipin'); ?> <?php echo $comments_number; ?> <?php _e('comments', 'ipin') ?></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php } 
            }   ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
        endwhile; 
        else :
        ?>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3"></div>

            <div class="span6">
                <div class="post-wrapper">
                    <div class="h1-wrapper">
                        <h1><?php _e( 'No Items Found', 'ipin' ); ?></h1>
                    </div>      

                    <div class="post-content text-align-center">
                    <p><?php _e('Perhaps searching will help.', 'ipin'); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span3"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
        <ul class="pager">
            <li id="navigation-next"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Previous', 'ipin')) ?></li>
            <li id="navigation-previous"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Next &raquo;', 'ipin')) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="scrolltotop"><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i><br /><?php _e('Top', 'ipin'); ?></a></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```